# Using decorate from another class in python 2.7

Tags: python, decorator, python-import, python-module, python-decorators

I am trying to call a decorator from another class in python. Below is the code

`file_1.py`

```
class ABC:
    def decorate_me(func):
        def wrapper():
            print "Hello I am in decorate_me func"
            print "Calling decorator function"
            func()
            print "After decorator"
        return wrapper
```

`file_2.py`

```
from file_1 import ABC
@ABC.decorate_me
def test():
    print "In test function ."

test()
```

output

```
TypeError: unbound method decorate_me() must be called with ABC instance as first argument (got function instance instead)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code in `file_2.py`:

```
from file_1 import ABC
dec = ABC.decorate_me
@dec
def test():
    print("In test function .")

test()
```

Output:

```
Hello I am in decorate_me func
Calling decorator function
In test function .
After decorator
```

Answer (score 3):

As hinted by the error, your decorator is a method; try making it a static function:

```
class ABC:
    @staticmethod
    def decorate_me(func):
        ...
```

But the question is why do you put it in `ABC`?

Comment: I want to use this decorator in number of classes. That is the reason I will put this in common class

Answer (score 1):

Since you decorator isn't using `self` it looks like the wrapper may be a staticmethod. If you declare `decorate_me` as such you can use it with `@ABC.deocarate_me`.

If you want to use this decorator in other classes, consider having the class with the decorator as a base class that your other classes inherit from. Another option is to not put your decorator in a class at all.

Comment: In this case not a `classmethod` but a `staticmethod`: a class method still needs the class.